# How to use the box2d contact listener in android (java port)?

Tags: android, java, box2d

I don't have any idea about the box2d collision detection in android. I googled and got results that suggest to use the contact listener but I don't know how to use it in android java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using JBox2D, you can use

```
org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG! that was the best help I've found! Thankyou Skyuzo.
This code works for JBox2D (I haven't tried Android however, but Android would be using JBox2D instead of the C++ Box2D)

Inside the ContactListener, this code must be placed handling the contacts:
*Note* This code should only be initialized once.

```
world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

            @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            System.out.println("Contact detected");
        }

        @Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            System.out.println("Contact removed");
        }

        @Override
        public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void preSolve(Contact arg0, Manifold arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can't figure out if this is an answer or a thank you.

Comment: Looks like both. It's the same answer but it has the abstract methods implemented.